# How can i change image after get data from database

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

For `function getDataFromDb()` I get newest data from database and I want to use `val["id"]`to define condition to change image you will see on `function GetImage` but it's not success. Can you give me for any example ?

```
<script>

function getDataFromDb()
{
    $.ajax({ 
                url: "getData.php" ,
                type: "POST",
                data: ''
            })
            .success(function(result) { 
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                    if(obj != '')
                    {
                          //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
                          $("#myBody").empty();
                          $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                                    var tr = "<tr>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["id"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["first_name"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["last_name"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["age"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["hometown"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["job"] + "</td>";
                                    // tr = tr + "<td>" + "<img src='" + GetImage(parseInt(val["id"]))+"'>" + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "</tr>";

                                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
                          });
                    }

            });

}

function GetImage(id){
    var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
    if (image.val["id"] < 10){
        return "pic/img1.jpg"
    } else if (image.val["id"] < 20){
        return "pic/img2.jpg"
    } else {
        return "pic/img3.jpg"
    };
}

setInterval(getDataFromDb, 100);   // 1000 = 1 second
</script>
```

Comment: what errors do you get? And, I also se that you are not actually using the id parameter in your GetImage function. Have you tried if (image.val[id] < 10){ ... }?

Answer (score 1):

uncomment the commented `tr` in `each` loop and use following function

```
function GetImage(id){

    if (id< 10){
        return "pic/img1.jpg"
    } else if (id< 20){
        return "pic/img2.jpg"
    } else {
        return "pic/img3.jpg"
    };
}
```